# Can I spend more time in country other than the one that issued my Schengen visa?

Tags: visas, schengen-visas

I am an Indian national, planning to apply to the Netherlands Embassy in San Francisco, US for a Schengen visa. I want to spend 16 days in the Netherlands and Italy.

I will fly to and from Amsterdam but, in between, I plan to go Italy.

Will it be okay if I stay in Italy longer than in the Netherlands and just return to Amsterdam for the last 3-4 days?

Comment: Have you read the Schengen visa rules?

Comment: Yeah, but still not clear.

Comment: If you are spending longer in Italy, why not apply to Italy for the visa?

Comment: You Need to apply at the Italian embassy, **not** the Netherlands embassy

Comment: Why are you planning to apply to the Dutch consulate instead of the Italian?  (The Dutch embassy in the US is in Washington, as are most embassies if not all; the post in San Francisco is a consulate.)

Comment: @phoog, sorry , i meant consulate. Its just that there is no sooner appointment available for Italian consulate, so changed my plan to spend time in Netherlands.

Comment: @devang I am in exact same situation as yours. applied at French but want to have more time in italy; couldn't apply at italy because no appointments were available. can u tell what u did amd if there were any problems?

Comment: @pranavk hi Pranav, luckily i got appointment at Italy Embassy. For long time I kept a watch on dates, and as soon as I got one, i scheduled it. For backup I did had a Dutch Embassy date, but chose to go Italian.

Comment: @devang Lucky you! I applied to the French already and would be taking an internal flight to Rome. Hopefully, they wouldn't get to know that I am using Paris just to enter/exit.

Answer (score 2):

You should apply at the embassy/consulate of the country which is the **main** destination of your trip. All other things being equal, the country where you spend the most time will be your main destination, but there can be exceptions.

- If you have a business meeting in the Netherlands, and if you add a week of sightseeing in Italy to that, the business meeting might still be the **main** purpose of the trip.
- Same if you have a family reunion or whatever in the Netherlands.

But if you distort the description of your trip to justify an application at the Netherlands, you risk a refusal/rejection because the premise sounds insincere to the visa officials. Telling the truth is the best policy on the long run. If you want to go to Italy, apply in Italy.

Comment: Its just that there is no sooner appointment available for Italian consulate, so changed my plan to spend time in Netherlands.